# Configuring the comparators

Tags: java, spring, comparator

I'm designing a solution where I need to choose different comparators based on input. Take an example below of what I have at the moment:

```
return MyComparator.compareVal1()
       .thenComparing(comparingVal2)
       .thenComparing(comparingVal3)
       .thenComparing(specificComparator)
       .thenComparing(comparingVal4)
       .compare(obj1, obj2);
```

I need these comparators to be configured. Based on my input, I should be executing a set of comparators. How can I possibly achieve that? I'm using Spring, Java 8.

Comment: You could create your own `Comparator` which takes the `input` as constructor argument. Something like `MyComparator comp = new MyComparator(input);`. Then you can use the value inside your comparator.

Comment: Give input - output example, please, I can't quite understand how do you want them to work.

Comment: I have some solution in mind but I need to understand what's your intended flow through this.